# How to use dcm4che extensively to develop StorageSCP?

Tags: dcm4che

I want to listen in some port like 1020 at localhost and i should receive DICOM images from the other node and want store it and also need to send all to PACS. Using dcm4chetool kit how can i achive this. please help me i am new in it. thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You would need dcm4chee to do it. Unless you write quite a bit of code around it, toolkit itself does not handle a lot of situations, e.g. if PACS you are forwarding to was not available for couple of seconds, you would have a problem.

Just follow installation steps from here: http://www.dcm4che.org/confluence/display/ee2/Home
After that, configure forwarding service: http://www.dcm4che.org/confluence/display/ee2/Forward+Service

It will take some time to understand and learn it, but otherwise it is stable and awesome tool.

Answer (score 0):

dcm4che2 can do just what you need for

You can take a look at the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/mip4j/source/browse/src/mod/org/dcm4che2/tool/DcmQR.java) of the tool dcmqr

or you can run a tutorial [C-MOVE](http://code.google.com/p/mip4j/source/browse/src/mip4j/tutorial/ex09/Transfer.java) example that i wrote in a project call mip4j, you will need basic PACS knowledge, such as setup AE title.

it look something like:

```
dcmqr.setCalling("DCMRCV"); // The AET known by the PACS Server
dcmqr.setLocalPort(11106);  // The AET known by the PACS Server
dcmqr.setMoveDest("DCMRCV");
dcmqr.setStoreDestination("R:/tmp");
```

By the way, send (C-STORE) example is also provided in that tutorial, take a look at ex6.